# Date formatting in iOS 9 not working

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, ios9

I'm have a problem with date formatting in iOS 9, it works ok with iOS 8 and also it works when I'm testing it in simulator with iOS 9, but when a test it on real device with iOS 9 I'm getting null. Below is code that I'm using

```
NSLog(@"String Date: '%@'", stringDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
```

In log I'm getting:

```
String Date: '8/29/2015 4:13:39 PM'
Date: (null)
```

Also if I use uppercase h (H or HH) I'm always getting that hour is 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting locale on your date formatter.

```
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7):

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a
>   locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results
>   regardless of both user and system preferences.

**EDIT:** Swift Version

```
dateFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Comment: How this will work on swift?

Comment: Please see my updated post. @YestayMuratov